# Transient overvoltage protection by varistor

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics

Using a varistor is a common practice  in alternator excitation system. It is used with rotating rectifier diode.
Is it used for transient overvoltage protection?
[image]

Is it protecting diode or rotor winding.
How this overvoltage may occur?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be more appropriate in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: This is now posted on the Electrical stack so needs to be removed.